# Best protocol of Web Services for Python based applications

Tags: python, web-services, rest, soap

Can anyone suggest best protocol to be used for Web Services (SOAP or REST) for Python for real time data and historical data fetching.
Please suggest the libraries available if any.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Answer (score 0):

REST protocol should be used.

For Django based application use [Django rest framework package](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

For Flask based application use [Flask restful package](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/)